# How to create a searchable list of buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have buttons in a list format. I would like to be able to search through the buttons with this or another search script. It is currently not working with this code.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Please type a keyword." title="FAQ Search">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-btn w3-white w3-hide-small"><i class="fa fa-info w3-margin-center"></i>How To Use This Site</button>
    <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
      <div class="w3-modal-content">
        <div class="w3-container">
          <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span>
          <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><button onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" class="w3-btn w3-white w3-hide-small"><i class="fa fa-info w3-margin-center"></i>When to use</button>
    <div id="id02" class="w3-modal">
      <div class="w3-modal-content">
        <div class="w3-container">
          <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span>
          <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone have script that would allow me to search through these buttons?

Comment: What do you mean by "search through buttons"? What isn't working in your script? Are you getting any errors in console? What debugging steps have you gone through to solve the issue?

Comment: _`a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];`_ No `<li>` elements have child element `<a>`  at `html` at Question

Comment: No errors. It just will not search through the list. I mean in a list format, this will filter out anything not in your search query. This however, does not filter when using buttons. I need to use buttons, or something similar, so that I can have pop ups when users click on each button

Comment: As far as debugging steps. Too many to post all of the script. I have attempted different pop up scripts, using and not using list items, not having buttons, and just using pop ups, among others

Comment: See the answer by @quirimmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `li` items there are no `a` elements.
Just change this line:

```
a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
```

to:

```
a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Please type a keyword." title="FAQ Search">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-btn w3-white w3-hide-small"><i class="fa fa-info w3-margin-center"></i>How To Use This Site</button>
    <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
      <div class="w3-modal-content">
        <div class="w3-container">
          <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span>
          <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><button onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" class="w3-btn w3-white w3-hide-small"><i class="fa fa-info w3-margin-center"></i>When to use</button>
    <div id="id02" class="w3-modal">
      <div class="w3-modal-content">
        <div class="w3-container">
          <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span>
          <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

p.s. Of course also changing the name of the variable to something meaningful would be nice considering it is not an `a` element...